# Why the naming: NodeList vs childNodes

Tags: dom, naming-conventions, standards, theory

I have been wondering about a stupid thing about the DOM. Why do the standards define NodeList with the postfix `List` to make it clear it is an array while have a some properties or functions like `childNodes` or `getElementsByTagName` which use the postfix letter `s`?

I find it contradictory when the standards define members with different suffixes for the same purpose (to describe an array).

Edit: It actually seems that NodeList is not even an array. Does this explain this?

Comment: Neither functions return arrays (they return NodeList instances).  Perhaps the reason is that having a Node class and a Nodes class could be confusing, so they chose NodeList to clear up ambiguity...?

Comment: They could have called it `ListOfNodes`. That would have had the `s` postfix. But `NodeList` is shorter and sounds better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeList` is an interface.

`childNodes` is a member of the `Node` interface.
`getElementsByTagName` is a member of the `Document` interface.

BTW, both these members return a value of type `NodeList`.

So, there is a difference: one is an interface, and the other two are members of interfaces.

Comment: So, you are saying they name interfaces with List word and members with the letter s?

Comment: @rFactor afaik, NodeList is the only interface that ends with "List". NodeList and NamedNodeMap are (afaik) the only interfaces that represent collections - all other interfaces represent individual objects. My guess is that the name "NodeList" was chosen out of convenience.. they could have went with ListOfNodes all the same.